# Hard switching a filter on and off without dropping the voltage

Tags: switches, filter

I am trying to design a circuit that functions as a low pass filter for the DC electrodes of an ion trap. But I would like to be able to hard switch the filter off so that during the loading of the trap I can run a small RF signal to kick out unwanted ions, and then switch back to the filter mode after. I created the circuit below but the problem is when I flip the switch the voltage drops completely and kicks out all of my ions. I am wondering if there is a way to minimize this voltage drop when the switch gets flipped?

[image]

Comment: A filter implies states and in this case the state is the capacitor. Switching it results in different past values at the time of the re-connection, thus it's impossible to do it without transients, unless you're dealing with a mildly varying DC. For AC, there are very (very) small chances you'd be switching back to a similar value of voltage across the capacitor so that there is very little variation.

Comment: Maybe replace the switch with a potentiometer, then you can have some manual "analog" control of it, and maybe bring it in "gently".   Something like a 1k-10k  probably would be suitable  (Not knowing anything else about your application...)

Answer (score 0):

With your current circuit, when you flip the switch the connect the capacitor into the circuit, the capacitor is initially discharged and so the voltage across it is 0V - which is as you've observed.
I'd suggest a different arrangement using an additional resistor to 'pre-charge' the cap to its operating voltage so that at the moment of switchover there's no sudden change in voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzqCni.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So now with the switch open, C1 charges up to the level of V1 through R2. Then when you close the switch there's no sudden change in voltage.

Comment: Another approach would be to add a large resistor across SW1 in your original circuit (I'd say about 470K depending on leakage characteristics of other components) to keep C1 charged without allowing it to pass significant AC current.